# Multi display: how to restore last gVim display?

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc

I have 2 displays.
I start gVim. It window always opens on display 1. I move it to dislpay 2 then close it. After this I start gVim again. It opens on display 1 again but I want it to open on display 2.

How to make gVim open its window on previous display?

I tried [this script](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_screen_size_and_position) but it does not restore last display. It always opens window on display 1.

Comment: Which OS? If Linux, which desktop manager?  Do other apps behave like you want?

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming that you always want gvim to open on display 2.

One solution is using the excellent wmctrl utility

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

via which you can make all kinds of adjustments to your window setups. It allows you to reach in and change the operations of your window manager.

OK, I don't know the location of display 2 in your setup, but just presuming that display 2's top left corner is at the x,y location 999, 9(or, more likely, 1025,0 or somesuch), and the dimensions of your display #2 are 1001 x 1002 the command

```
gvim; sleep 0.1; wmctrl -r gvim -e 0,999,9,1001,1002
```

will run gvim and move it to your display #2 and make the window full size on that display.

I would then make that the permanent definition of gvim. In my ~/.bashrc or /etc/bash.bashrc or whatever configuration file you use, I would write (the shell-appropriate variant of):

```
alias gvim='gvim; sleep 0.1; wmctrl -r gvim -e 0,999,9,1001,1002'
```